# Nginx Redirect (site.com/ru/ to site.com) Request Должен передоватся

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

Мой конфиг Nginx 1.14.0

```
server {
server_name site.com www.site.com;
ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/mydevana/newm.crtca";
ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/mydevana/newm.key";
ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
charset off;
index index.php index.html;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
ssi on;
set $root_path /var/www/mydevana/data/www/site.com;
root $root_path;
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
        expires 1d;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
}
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    access_log off;
}
listen 111.11.111.111:443 ssl http2;
```

Нужно перенаправить 
site.com/ru to site.com с сохранением Request

Пример:
site.com/ru/banana/sort-banana to site.com/banana/sort-banana

site.com/ru/audi/r8 to site.com/audi/r8

Без циклической переадресации!

**ОБРАЩАЮ ваше внимание это с ssl!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^\/ru\/ {
    rewrite  ^/ru/(.*)  /$1  permanent;
}
```

Comment: Не знал что Nginx server{} категория  расширяется на под категории с помощью location